# Source for a Pesach niggun

Tags: passover, music

I heard a niggun for ma nishtana this year (my recording [here](https://record.reverb.chat/s/atfQBmbyYaFcq1Onel9F)) that goes "ma-a-a nish-ta-na ha-a-a-a-layla ha-la-ayla-a-a-ha-ze" that apparently might be from somewhere in Poland and was on Yiddish records in the 50s/60s)

I'm wondering if anyone recognizes it or knows where it is from. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the beautiful voice. The niggun is _slightly_ reminiscent of Frere Jacques towards the end

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The song is a chassidic niggun for Mah Nishtanah, I don't have more information on the historical background.

It is on Lchaim Tish by Yosef Moshe Kahana. available here https://open.spotify.com/track/5vapru0AWJzBe6wDd8x1Jt?si=7831430f61864a1e.
or here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jp6pJOV1lkw on the track of Mah Nishtanah

[image]

Comment: are all songs on L'Chaim Tish Belz?

Comment: I think the melody for the "ma nishtana halayla haze" is correct, but the niggun I heard had a similar continuation whereas this one goes into the seperate yiddish "four questions" melody and I'm curious if anyone has the full original. Thanks!

Comment: @RabbiKaii edited. I thought it was but to in case i am wrong i changed